I'm trying to figure out who the artist is on a painting. (Characters identified: on the seal 曹蘇斯 and the calligraphy 我心畫)
Had this painting for about a decade, asked for a translation of the text one reddit and this is what they were able to provide me.
我心畫 Ambiguous, perhaps "painted with my heart" or painted by "Woxin"?
Seal reads 曹蘇斯 Cao Susi. 蘇斯 is a transliteration of the name Sossei.
Looking to hopefully get more info on this. Thanks in advance for the help.
.

Finally figured out how to add an image in-line

我心画 may means painted with my heart, 我心 is unlikely to be a personal name cause the seal on the painting.
The seal in a Chinese paintings were often used to indicate authorship or who got the painting, and here was only one seal means that the character in the seal was the name of the author of this painting. Therefore, the seal means 曹蘇斯(maybe Sossei is the author's real name and the author is not a Chinese) painted this Chinese painting.
